# flex-flow:row-reverse wrap-reverse in reverse order html and css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a content and I Want them in row-reverse and wrap-reverse but with reverse order.
Here's code:

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 520px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background-color: black;
}

.b {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="b">3</div>
  <div class="b">4</div>
  <div class="b">5</div>
  <div class="b">6</div>
</div>
```

The order should be reversed.
Please answer this without using 'order' property.
Something like this image(sorry for bad edit):

[image]

Please see code output first then image.

Comment: why do not use with order??

Comment: the data is added dynamically and it could go till 1000 of div block

Comment: Do u HAVE to use flexbox?

Comment: Yes,to make the application responsive,I need flexbox.

Comment: If the data is being added dynamically, why not have the blocks stacked in reverse order in the HTML? Newer blocks stack on top. https://jsfiddle.net/mwmdduj0/2/

Comment: Or use a script to add an `order` value to each new block. Here's the idea, illustrated in CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/mwmdduj0/3/

Comment: @Michael_B i'm just curious, I suggested a solution which I think meets the OP's criteria and also doesn't require js - do you see a problem with it?

Comment: @Danield, I'll read your answer and respond when I'm on my desktop.. Can't do much from mobile.

Comment: @Danield I can not know for sure, but **b** elements have a min-width and not a width. If any element has a content that exceeds the min-width, it can lead to a row with 3 elements. Anyway, this should be said by the OP.

Comment: Not a direct answer for your problem but if you use an array for rendering your items, just reverse your array first.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of [Quantity Queries](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) to implement this layout (**no js required!**)

## Demo Snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
li:nth-last-child(4n + 3):first-child {
  margin-left: 125px;
  background-color: pink;
}
li:nth-last-child(4n + 2):first-child {
  margin-left: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}
li:nth-last-child(4n + 1):first-child {
  margin-left: 375px;
  background-color: green;
}
li:nth-last-child(4n):first-child {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

## Explanation:

The layout required here essentially boils down to a regular four-column left to right layout with the first element indented according to how many items there are in the container.

When there are 4n items (4, 8, 12 etc) - no indentation is required.

When there are 4n + 1 items (1, 5, 9 etc) - a three-item indentation is required.

When there are 4n + 2 items (2, 6, 10 etc) - a two-item indentation is required.

When there are 4n + 3 items (3, 7, 11 etc) - a one-item indentation is required.

## Relevant CSS:

```
li:nth-last-child(4n + 3):first-child {
  margin-left: 125px; /* one-item indentation */
}
li:nth-last-child(4n + 2):first-child {
  margin-left: 250px; /* two-item indentation */
}
li:nth-last-child(4n + 1):first-child {
  margin-left: 375px; /* three-item indentation */
}
li:nth-last-child(4n):first-child {
  /* no indentation */
}
```

### To understand this, let's use the OP's example:

Say there are 6 items. We need to apply a two-item indentation to the first item.

The selector for this would be:

```
li:nth-last-child(4n + 2):first-child {
  margin-left: 250px; /* 250 = 2 * 120 (item width) + 2 * 5px gap */
}
```

The interesting bit is `:nth-last-child(4n + 2):first-child` which means:

'select the first child if it is also the 4n + 2 child from the last child.'

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/MXgoea)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of doing this is using JS to calculate the margin the first element should have to the left by using the modulus like in the snippet below.

```js
const offset = document.querySelectorAll('.a .b').length%4;
const width = 120 + 5; //min-height + margin, it's probably better to calculate this value.
document.querySelector('.a .b').style.marginLeft = `${width*offset}px`;
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 520px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}

.b {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="b">3</div>
  <div class="b">4</div>
  <div class="b">5</div>
  <div class="b">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible way? So untested or verified?

Comment: @Rob: possible because it's definitely not the only way to achieve this. You can run the code snippet for yourself and verify if it has the desired behaviour.

Comment: @LuudJacobs the data is dynamically added,so if I add 1 more div,then first div should shift left but its not doing so in your answer.

Comment: @AbuTaha That's true. After adding a new `<div/>` the JS code should first remove the margin it set previously and then run again to set the margin to the first item.